# Laravel Eloquent - Get data from 3 tables with consecutive foreign keys

Tags: sql, database, laravel, join

I'm looking for a way to join 3 Data Tables.

```
 table a
 -------
 a_id
 b_id 
 a_val

 table b
 --------
 b_id
 c_id
 b_val

 table c
 --------
 c_id
 c_val
```

Laravel Query;

```
$join = DB::table('a')->join('b', 'b.b_id', 'a.b_id')->get();
```

How to fetch data from table 'c' by applying a query on table 'a'?

i'm new to Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it is not as much related to laravel it needs knowledge of the database.
You can join 3 tables like this.

```
$join = DB::table('a')->join('b', 'b.b_id', 'a.b_id')->join('c','b.c_id','c.c_id')->select('c.c_id','c.c_cval')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, brother!
You saved me alot of time..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at eloquent relationships on how to connect models.
specifically of use to you is the hasOneThrough() or hasManyThrough() functionalities

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through